# PHP / MSSQL: DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Always Displays As 1

Tags: php, sql

I am returning the column names from a table, and want to return the Data Type of those columns to define search criteria. I have the code as I would expect for returning any data from any table. However DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS always appears to return as the value 1.

```
<?php

$column_names_sql = "SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='HardwareAsset'";

$column_names = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $column_names_sql);

echo "<option value=''>Select Attribute</option>";
while ($column_names_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($column_names)) {

    if ($column_names_option->ORDINAL_POSITION == 2) {

        echo "<option value='$column_names_option->COLUMN_NAME'>" . preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', str_replace(['HardwareAsset', 'ID'], ' ', $column_names_option->COLUMN_NAME)) . "</option>";
    }
    if (($column_names_option->ORDINAL_POSITION !== 1 && $column_names_option->ORDINAL_POSITION !== 2) && ($column_names_option->DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' && $column_names_option->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH < '256')) {

        echo "<option value='$column_names_option->COLUMN_NAME' type='$column_names_option->DATA_TYPE'>" . preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', str_replace(['HardwareAsset', 'ID'], ' ', $column_names_option->COLUMN_NAME)) . "</option>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is what the select returns as:

```
<option value="HardwareAssetAssetTag" type="1"> Asset Tag</option>
```

Comment: You are assigning instead of comparing in your second if statement: `$column_names_option->DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'`

Comment: but that if returns all data types excluding those as defined in the if?

Comment: that has fixed it though removing it, thanks, i will work on the IF

Comment: You don't need to remove it, you need to make a comparison (`... == 'varchar'`) instead of an assignment (`... = 'varchar'`)